# Error: Could not autoload /puppet/pops/binder/hiera2/json_backend: no such file to load -- json

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I try to setup a Vagrant instance with a puphpet script and get the following error message:

```
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/git/lib/facter/git_exec_path.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/git/lib/facter/git_version.rb
Error: Could not autoload /puppet/pops/binder/hiera2/json_backend: no such file to load -- json
Error: Could not autoload /puppet/pops/binder/hiera2/json_backend: no such file to load -- json on node devbox.local
Error: Could not autoload /puppet/pops/binder/hiera2/json_backend: no such file to load -- json on node devbox.local
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
```

Does anybody as a hint what might be wrong?
Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "gem install json" before "gem install librarian-puppet" in the file {vagrant path}/puphpet/shell/librarian-puppet-vagrant.sh (probably somewhere around line 72)

I was having a similar issue and found the above solution at https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/455. My issue had nothing to do with the proxy stuff mentioned there, however the json errors were similar to mine. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Vagrant to 1.4.3 and I'm starting to get the same error, so it's possible it's a bug that's only appeared in the latest revision.
Not sure how you would roll back to 1.3.5, remove and re-install?